# LinkedIn javascript API to obtain full user profile data

Tags: linkedin-api

I am experimenting with the LinkedIn javascript API using javascript/asp.net

I have got it so that I can log in using the LinkedIn button and retrieve the firstName, lastName data as per their example, but I would like to extract a full profiles-worth of data.

I have seen in the documentation that it is possible to obtain an XML file of a users profile, but I could not find any sample code that would let me do this for myself.

Does anyone out there know how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29279057/accessing-r-fullprofile-after-new-linkedin-api-policy-changes