# Accessing r_fullprofile after new LinkedIn API policy changes

Tags: linkedin-api

Is the only way to access `r_fullprofile` by applying for LinkedIn partnership after the new API policy?

My application is currently using it for fetching the users "Skills" which requires `r_fullprofile` instead of `r_basicprofile`.

Would I need to do any changes regarding the new policy if I only used `r_basicprofile`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As per LinkedIn's documentation, "skills" fields are only available under the `r_fullprofile` member permission (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/full-profile) when making an API call to request member data.

After May 12th, 2015, apps will no longer be able to request this member permission without being specifically reviewed by LinkedIn for compliance with the Apply with LinkedIn use case (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin) or some other partnership program membership which grants access to that permissions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If we decide to drop skills / `r_fullprofile` from our application and only include `r_basicprofile`, are we required to do any other changes before May 12th?

Comment: @justin can you clarify if `r_basicprofile` will be fully accessible after May 12 w/out a partner agreement?

Comment: Yes, `r_basicprofile` will still be available to everyone after May 12th.

Comment: Agh! I just noticed my app stopped working because of r_fullprofile. In none of the notices about the change from LinkedIn did they every mention a review process! I am 100% sure our non-profit's use is in full compliance. Sigh.

Comment: It pains me that in order to find out what was going on here I had to Google it and find the answer on SO. It's crazy that there is no link to let you apply directly from https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/full-profile

Answer (score 6):

**Starting from [May 12, 2015](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes), Linkedin has limited the open APIs. 
Access to `r_fullprofile` requires that you apply for and are granted access to this information from LinkedIn.**

**WHAT YOU NEED TO DO :**

Apply for partner status with LinkedIn ([Apply with Linkedin](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin)), explaining what your integration is and how it works. If it meets their criteria, then you will get access to those endpoints, but only for that app.

**Member profile fields**

The following selection of profile fields are available to all LinkedIn developers:

1. Basic Profile Fields
2. Location Fields
3. Position Fields

**Member profile fields available to Apply with LinkedIn developers:**

The following selection of profile fields are only available to applications that have applied and been approved for the Apply with LinkedIn use case:

1. Full Profile Fields
2. Contact Info Fields
3. Company Fields
4. Publication Fields
5. Patent Fields
6. Language Fields
7. Skill Fields
8. Certification Fields
9. Course Fields
10. Education Fields
11. Volunteer Fields

**Check out this [linkedin page](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields) for more details on which fields are available to all the developers and which are not.**

Comment: LinkedIn help says like ,This is ([Apply for LinkedIn] (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin) currently unavailable. We’re improving our partner program application process. Updates will be posted on developer.linkedin.com. Thank you for your patience while we work on this.

Last updated: 9 months ago