# LinkedIn OAuth Exception Scope NOT_AUTHORIZED r_fullprofile

Tags: oauth, ruby-on-rails-3.2, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

Everything worked well until today when I received an email from LinkedIn indicating some significant API changes. And subsequently I was seeing Exceptions while authenticating users via. LinkedIn.

> Following is the exception from logs

```
OAuth::Problem (Scope NOT_AUTHORIZED : r_fullprofile):
  oauth (0.4.7) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:178:in `request'
  oauth (0.4.7) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:194:in `token_request'
  oauth (0.4.7) lib/oauth/consumer.rb:136:in `get_request_token'
```

> OAuth logic to get request token.

```
consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(LINKED_IN_API_KEY, LINKED_IN_SECRET_KEY,
                 {
                   :site               => "https://api.linkedin.com",
                   :scheme             => :header,
                   :http_method        => :post,
                   :request_token_path => "/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_fullprofile",
                   :access_token_path  => "/uas/oauth/accessToken",
                   :authorizeEmapath     => "/uas/oauth/authorize"
                 })

### Exception occurs at this call.
request_token = consumer.get_request_token(:oauth_callback => callback_url)
```

> Email from LinkedIn

[image]

> My Analysis till now

If I change the scope to `r_basicprofile` it works fine but then I don't get `skills` info of the authenticated linkedin user.

What should be the additional changes I need to do to suffice the API change ?

Answer (score 6):

**Starting from [May 12, 2015](https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes), Linkedin has limited the open APIs.**

Access to `r_fullprofile` scopes requires that you apply for and are granted access to this information from LinkedIn. The full profile fields are only available to applications that have applied and been approved for the [Apply with LinkedIn](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin) use case.

**SOLUTION:**

Apply for partner status with LinkedIn, explaining what your integration is and how it works. If it meets the criteria of **"we feel that they’re providing value to members, developers and LinkedIn,"** then some or all of the restricted endpoints will remain open for that app, and ONLY that app.

**Member profile fields**

The following selection of profile fields are available to all LinkedIn developers:

1. Basic Profile Fields
2. Location Fields
3. Position Fields

**Member profile fields available to Apply with LinkedIn developers:**

The following selection of profile fields are only available to applications that have applied and been approved for the Apply with LinkedIn use case:

1. Full Profile Fields
2. Contact Info Fields
3. Company Fields
4. Publication Fields
5. Patent Fields
6. Language Fields
7. Skill Fields
8. Certification Fields
9. Course Fields
10. Education Fields
11. Volunteer Fields

**Check out this [linkedin page](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields) for more details on which fields are available to all the developers and which are not.**

Answer (score 3):

I tried this https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,skills,educations,languages,twitter-accounts)?format=json at https://apigee.com/console/linkedin.

It is giving skills at apigee, but here https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields , Skills are something you would need to be approved by Linkedin.

Comment: It works with OAuth 2.0. But am trying to authorize with `/uas/oauth/requestToken`. Which is OAuth1a.

Comment: I thing I have found my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/29286533/1125893 r_fullprofile can be requested but with 'Apply-with-linkedIn' strategy.

Comment: @swap.nil , Heres the Link for Apply with Linked if you need it [link](https://help.linkedin.com/app/ask/path/api-dvr)