# Linkedin Rest API suddenly stopped working

Tags: ruby, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm developing a Rails app, which contains importing of profile information from LinkedIn to a Rails DB.
It works fine a lot of the time, but over the last 2 weeks it suddenly stopped working...

- Default Application Permissions on LinkedIn is only `r_fullprofile`
- I use `linkedin` gem as a wrapper
- Fields to import - `positions`, `educations`, `summary`, `languages`, `picture-url`

Error, which I see in PROD logs:

```
    LinkedIn connect failed: Scope NOT_AUTHORIZED : r_fullprofile
    .rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:178:in `request'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:194:in `token_request'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:136:in `get_request_token'
    .rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/linkedin-0.4.3/lib/linked_in/helpers/authorization.rb:22:in `request_token'
```

As I see in debug, for some reason `request token and secret` are `nil`,
so I decide that the API to authorize client with my linkedin-app does not work.

ALso, I found [an answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29286533/1523560) that some API rules were changed some time ago:

> After May 12th, 2015, apps will no longer be able to request this
>   member permission without being specifically reviewed by LinkedIn for
>   compliance with the Apply with LinkedIn use case
>   (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/apply-with-linkedin) or some
>   other partnership program membership which grants access to that
>   permissions.

But, does some analog of `r_fullprofile` permisson exists now, which give an access to get all profile information from linkedin?

Comment: That means we can access the position/skills from `r-fullprofile` scope? If yes, could you please have a look at :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849520/how-to-fetch-linkedin-user-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I found in [Developer Program Transition Guide](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition):

Access to the r_fullprofile member permission now requires explicit approval from LinkedIn. Additionally, the focus of this permission has changed to become much more specific. Going forward, data received from the Profile API using the r_fullprofile permission can only be used to complement your company's careers pages, as described further on the Apply with LinkedIn page.

If you are already using member data provided by r_fullprofile and you believe your application meets new useage criteria, you will still be required to apply for permission on the Apply with LinkedIn page to maintain your application's ability to use the r_fullprofile member permission.

Here is a link for Apply with LinkedIn if you need it: 
https://help.linkedin.com/app/ask/path/api-dvr

I have asked for restoring API-access from my application, 
hope that LinkedIn support help me.

Use Apply with LinkedIn to:

Round out your knowledge about a candidate’s background, their recommendations, interests and who’s in their network
Incorporate a candidate’s full profile data in your careers site
Make it easy for qualified candidates to apply to your company’s jobs

And in a few days I received an answer that my access to API is restored!
Thanks LinkedIn Review Team, they are great guys!

Comment: I wouldn't count on it... if your app doesn't fit the four scenarios mentioned in the transition guide, its almost 100% guaranteed to be denied.

Comment: @NigelSheridan-Smith which scenarious?

Comment: @NigelSheridan-Smith As I understood, my app should not be denied, cause all functionality which I use is - when user click "import" button, my app authorize to linkedin, get user profile data and import it to my app (import data from user's linkedin profile to my app user's profile). Am I right?

Comment: LinkedIn has changed priorities and consequently dropped a substantial number of apps, by substantially reducing their permissions to the LI data. Unless they see value in what you app does, you will restricted to only basic permissions (individual user, their current position, their current company, basic profile data) - I am referring specifically to the Partner Program but maybe "Apply with LinkedIn" is different

Comment: Here are the four 'reasons' for using the LinkedIn Open APIs: https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes

Comment: @NigelSheridan-Smith does some other way to get user's `positions`, `educations`, `summary`, `languages`, `picture-url` without  `r_fullprofile` permission exists?

Comment: I don't think so... `r_network` works at the moment, but probably won't in the future. Here is a good summary of what is available inside and outside the program: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields